# Kotlin for game dev

Tags: garbage-collection, kotlin

Background:

I'm always searching for a language to replace Java for game development. Kotlin looks promising with a good IDE support and Java interop. But one of the FPS killers for a game (on Android especially) is GC usage. So, some libraries (like libgdx) are using pools of objects, custom collections and other tricks to avoid frequent GC run. For Java that can be done in a clear way. Some other JVM languages espesially with functional support using a lot of GC by it's nature, so it is hard to avoid.

Questions:

1. Does Kotlin creates any invisible GC overhead in comparison to Java?
2. Which features of Kotlin is better to avoid to have less GC work?

Comment: This question is too vague.  I suggest you experiment with this yourself.  Note: even if you see a `new` it doesn't mean the JVM will create an object as it can be optimised away.

Comment: I'm not a Kotlin expert. Maybe someone had already made some experiments and spent a time. That is why SO exist: to share experience, isn't it?

Comment: StackOverflow exists to give definitive answers to specific questions.  For a question like this, I suggest asking a kotlin forum.  Trying to predict in advance how something will perform is very hard, (Most experts know enough to not do this except in really obvious cases) I suggest you set up realist tests and attempt to profile them and benchmark them.

Comment: @alex.dorokhov topics that are too broad, or mostly opinion based are likely to be closed.  Hit the flag button on your own post and read the descriptions for reasons it might be closed.  Asking others to do significant homework for you (that's Google's job) fits into the too broad category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, Kotlin generates bytecode as close as possible to the one generated by Java. So, for example, if you use a function as a value, an inner class will be created, like in Java, but no more. There are also some optimization tricks like `IntArray` and `inline` to perform even better.

And as @Peter-Lawrey said, it's always a better idea to measure the values for your specific case.

Answer (score 10):

You can write Kotlin Code for the JVM which causes the same allocations than the Java corresponding logic. In both cases you have to carefully check if a library call allocates new memory on the heap, or not. Using Kotlin in combination with [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) doesn't introduce any *invisible GC overhead*. It's an effective way and works well (especially with the [ktx](https://github.com/libktx/ktx) extension.

But there are Kotlin language features which may help you to write your code with fewer allocations.

1. Singletons are a language feature. ([Object declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations), [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html) )
2. You can create wrapper classes for primitive types which compile to primitives. But you get the power of type safety and rich domain models ([Inline classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html#inline-classes)).
3. With the combination of [Operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading) and [Inline Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) you can build nice APIs which modify objects without allocating new ones. (Example: [Allocation-free Vectorial operations using custom operators](https://soywiz.com/kotlin-allocation-free-vectorial-operations-using-custom-operators/))
4. If you use any kind of dependency injection mechanism or object pooling to connect your game logic and reuse objects, then [Reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) may help to use it in a very elegant an short way. You can skip a class as type parameter, if the compiler knows the actual type.

But there is also another option which indeed gives you a different behavior in memory management. Thanks to [Kotlin Multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html), you can write your game logic as Kotlin common module and cross compile it to native code or to Javascript.
I did this in a sample Game project [Candy Crush Clone](https://github.com/TobseF/Candy-Crush-Clone). It works with [Korge](https://korge.soywiz.com/) a *Modern Multiplatform Game Engine for Kotlin*. The game runs on the JVM, as HTML web app and as Native binary in Win, Linux, Mac, Android or IOS.
The native compiled code has its own [simpler garbage collection](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/FAQ.md#q-what-is-kotlinnative-memory-management-model) and can [run faster](https://slides.com/tobsefritz/kotlin-native-multiplatform#/5/2). So the speed-increase and the different memory management may give you the power reserve to bother even less with the GC.

In conclusion I can recommend Kotlin for Game dev, also for GC critical scenarios. In my projects I tend to create more classes and allocate more memory when I write Kotlin code. But this is a question of programming style, not a technical one.

Comment: wow that was great answer. I have started learning Kotlin now. Btw do I need Java background to learn Kotlin ? Im also using KorGE

Answer (score 3):

Technically, your questions comparing Kotlin to Java are moot, they will perform the same.  But Kotlin will be a better development experience.

If Java is good for writing Games, then Kotlin would only better due to developer productivity.

**Note:**  the gaming library [LWJGL 3](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3) uses Kotlin in part, with GitHub stats showing 67.3% of the code being Kotlin (template module looks to be mostly Kotlin).  So asking people who work with LWJGL will give you the best answer to this question since they have a lot of experience in this area.

[image: Github Language Stats for LWJGL3]